# Safe/ less damaging way or method to attach/ screw these wall hook fixtures for easier future removal?

Tags: concrete, screws, drill, brick

So I've got 2 (small 4 hook) + 1 (Long 6 hook)  of these collapsing hook fixtures (each has 2/3 holes for screws) as shown in pictures. I've tried to label the surrounding things as well as I can.

This is currently at my family's home where I needed some functional modifications in my current room.

Problem is I may end up changing rooms in few months or move to a separate apartment and would like to have these fixtures wherever I end up staying for longer.

Also, these were the last few pieces in stock and are not being manufactured anymore and I didn't like any others after lot of hours of physical leg work during market search (in humid Asia).

I'll either have to buy or borrow some tools or ask someone to help me do this.

So I'd like to attach/ screw in these fixtures with following in mind:

- Least damage to fixture & wall during attachment
- Easy remove ability with minimal damage to both during detachment
- Easy cleanup, filling of holes etc once done

The construction is concrete columns & beams & walls are mostly brick, so I'm not sure what's behind the surface in each of the above variations/ scenario.

So is there a way or method or "dos & donts"  from experienced folks/ experts for someone who is a newbie to DIY stuff, at ones family's home.

PS: Any tips on whether placement looks better in line with top of frame or slightly moved below the line of the wood frames

[image: 4 hook folding collapsing wall hanging]

[image: 6 hook, folding collapsing wall door hanging fixture]

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a good way to solve your problem with your existing hooks that meet all of your requirements. Instead you should use 3M Command Hooks. They are removable and stick really well, and for your door you can attach as many as you need of them in a row.

Save your existing hooks for when you eventually move out. [image: 3M Command]

Comment: Thanks. They're not available here. Is there a good how to screw things tutorial with minimal damage?

Comment: @AlexS Yup, light pressure on the drill when using the masonry drill bit  is important to not blow out the face of your concrete wall. https://www.familyhandyman.com/masonry/pouring-concrete/how-to-choose-and-use-concrete-fasteners/view-all/